# Can I alt-tab out of Minecraft without the game auto-pausing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to alt-tab out of Minecraft (i.e. make Minecraft lose focus) without the game auto-pausing and without having to bring a menu (e.g. inventory) up first?

Comment: What's the problem with having a menu up? Granted, it would be *nice* otherwise, but is it causing any *specific* problems you're trying to avoid?

Comment: It fills most of the screen and dims the bits that it doesn't fill.  That makes me a bit nervous, as I can't see what's going on.

Comment: @BrianBeckett Things have changed a lot since 2011. If you're still having this issue, I'd recommend testing out one of the other answers (especially [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/128615/151208)), and possibly updating the accepted one, so others can find the most up-to-date info easily.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For single player, it seems that you've already figured out that bringing up the inventory screen prevents the game from auto-pausing when it loses focus.  I don't believe there is any other way to prevent the auto pausing.

You may, however, consider hosting a SMP server and being the only person connected to it.  In SMP, the game will not pause when you are alt-tabbed out.  You can install mods on a SMP server that allow you to create user whitelists to define who you want to connect to your server.  If you add only yourself to that list, you don't need to worry about anyone else connecting while you are playing.

Comment: Thank you, that's a really good idea!  Is it possible to pause an SMP game at all, by the way?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure, since I've never actually run an SMP server, only played on them.  I would assume there's a command to do it, and I'm sure it happens if you stop the server.  If you don't want the game to continue when you're not playing, simply stopping the server when you stop playing seems to be an easy solution.

Comment: @Cosmic - Another thing I wanted to mention - whether you're playing SSP or SMP, alt-tabbing will bring up the same menu as when you hit escape.  The difference is that when on an SMP server, the game won't pause in the background.  If this isn't sufficient, you probably won't find an easy solution to the problem.

Comment: @Cosmic Flame Yes, via [/stop](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Server_commands). :)

Comment: Note that nowadays you can just "Open to LAN", so there's no need to bring up a standalone server.

Answer (score 103):

Go into your minecraft folder and open up `options.txt`. Find the line that reads

```
pauseOnLostFocus:true
```

and change `true` to `false`. Now Minecraft won't pause to the menu screen when you tab away.

---

You can find your minecraft folder in a couple ways:

1. Using the file system: Navigate to...

   - `%appdata%\.minecraft\` (on Windows)
   - `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/` (on Mac OS X)
   - `~/.minecraft/` (on Linux)
2. Using Minecraft's menus:

   1. Start Minecraft and click **Options**, **Resource Packs**, and then **Open resource packs folder**. In the file system window that opens, go up one folder and you'll be in your minecraft folder.

Comment: This is definately the best way to do so that you don't have to change how your world works

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Remember to close minecraft before you make this change or else it will be overwritten by minecraft when minecraft closes

Comment: I don't know when it was added, but currently you can use F3+P to enable or disable `Pause on lost focus` in game.  It's a 'debug' setting like F3+G to show chunk borders.  See infmagic2047's answer.

Comment: It works. To make it take effect, please quit MC and change the setting, then restart  the game.

Answer (score 80):

You can press <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to let the game not auto-pausing. Press <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> again to re-enable it.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: It works very well for me (no message is displayed but it works).

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: @CorporalTouchy If you're on a laptop, you might need [fn]+[f3]+[p].

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i was searching for exactly this method :D

Comment: Should obviously be the accepted answer.

Comment: As in version 1.12.2 it displays a message about being disabled. It works as well.

Comment: be sure to hit those keys at the same time.

Comment: I got a message when I F3+P:  [Debug]: Pause on Lost Focus: disabled/enabled

Answer (score 15):

Since the update that merged the single- and multi-player code bases, **you can press T to start typing in chat, which will let you tab out without pausing or hiding the game**.

Comment: New favourite way!

Answer (score 4):

*This answer is no longer relevant to current Minecraft versions, because <kbd>F1</kbd> no longer hides menus; also, <kbd>F1</kbd> is now a toggle and the tricks for holding it down are irrelevant.*

Since you mention that your concern is that you can't see (as opposed to having the menu up at all), I have a fix for that: with the menu up, use <kbd>F1</kbd> to hide it. Pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> removes all HUD elements and leaves only the game view.

However, you have to hold down <kbd>F1</kbd>. There are several tricks for this to fool the game into thinking you have <kbd>F1</kbd> down:

- Press <kbd>F1</kbd> and switch out of Minecraft while holding it down. (Tested on Mac)
- Before releasing <kbd>F1</kbd>, press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> (Windows (and Linux?)) or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> (Mac) keys.
- Mac-specific: If you have a system where you have to press <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, just release <kbd>F1</kbd> before <kbd>fn</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst all the other solutions look perfectly fine, I thought I'd add the method I use, when I want to not have the game pause, I hit esc, and "Open up to LAN". The game doesn;t pause then on focus loss.

Answer (score 1):

This works for Minecraft Bedrock on Windows.

1. Press E to open your Inventory
2. Press E to close your inventory but immediately press ALT+TAB to switch to another (any other) window.

You need to get your ALT+TAB in while the Inventory is closing but it's not too difficult with a bit of practise.

Comment: Only option listed here that works for me for the Windows 10 UWP Bedrock Edition!

Answer (score 0):

here's how I did it, I was mining, in a map called Minevolution, I was in full screen mode and then, while holding down left click, I pressed F11 at the same time I let go of the left click button, and it continued to mine, then I just did the whole Alt+Tab thing to get out of it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you just open a LAN connection the game no longer can be paused, even if you're in the game menu. A LAN connection only allows people to jump in if they are on the same internet connection, so it is pretty secure.

Answer (score -2):

Changing the options is the best way to do it. In Multiplayer you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and Automine while pressing <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't let you do anything while AFK.