# Is there a way to prevent the pause menu from appearing when tabbing out of the game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm wanting to keep windows open of Minecraft for some live streaming, and have considered using multiple copies of Minecraft for multiple camera angles. However, if I <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> out of the game, the pause menu appears.

Are there any mods out there to prevent this from occurring?

This question is similar to [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15664/can-i-alt-tab-out-of-minecraft-without-the-game-auto-pausing), with the exception that I simply want nothing to be obstructing the view of the game during SMP.

Edit: The point is I want to stream the screen without having to be active in-game, so opening the crafting screen is out of the question.

Comment: I think your link is pointing to the wrong question.

Comment: Yup, didn't notice. Thanks for fixing Ben.

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I alt-tab out of Minecraft without the game auto-pausing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/15664/185203)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open a crafting/inventory/smelting window it will not pause the game when you ALT-TAB out of the game.

Try opening Chat window instead. (press <kbd>T</kbd>) The chat window is transperant, and the game is essentially "paused" (you can't move and use items) while it waits for you to type something. Obviously don't type anything and when you are done you can press <kbd>T</kbd> again to make it go away.

Comment: While the game won't pause, the inventory window will then be in front of the screen. The point is I want to do this for streaming, so I need to see the game.

Comment: If you press F1 it will remove it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The crafting stations and inventory will still show up when pressing F1, and pressing F1 again will not make it go away.

Comment: @WillEddins Were you notified about this edit? I think that's one feature SE still lacks, so let me notify you here.

Comment: A workable solution I suppose. Since I wanted this for streaming and recording, always showing the chat is a less-than-optimal solution. However, this mixed with some modification that perhaps makes the chat less noticeable may work. Since this is as close as I'm going to get, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>f3</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> toggles a mode in which you get exactly that, it doesn't pause automatically when not in focus.

Answer from: [Can I alt-tab out of Minecraft without the game auto-pausing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15664/can-i-alt-tab-out-of-minecraft-without-the-game-auto-pausing)