# How do I alt-tab out of fullscreen Minecraft with the game still running (Mac)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I regularly play Minecraft with a reference site, such as Minecraftwiki, open in a browser window. However, I haven't found an easy way to alt-tab between the game and a browser when the game is in full screen.

The fastest way I found yet is `Pause --> Options --> Video Settings --> Fullscreen off` but this becomes cumbersome pretty fast.

I've already found [these](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15664/can-i-alt-tab-out-of-minecraft-without-the-game-auto-pausing) [two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40949/how-do-i-alt-tab-out-of-full-screen-games-on-mac-os-x-lion) questions here, but none of the options given there seem to work.

I'm using Mac OS 10.8 and I've updated to the latest Minecraft release (1.6.4).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most fullscreen programs on Mac OS 10.8 will use the four-finger swipe to switch between it and the desktop, but Minecraft doesn't obey this protocol. It appears to use a borderless window the size of the desktop instead of creating and using a separate fullscreen space. It also appears to set itself to be always on top, so Minecraft won't relinquish focus when you use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

The only way I've found to quickly switch is, as you have, to turn off fullscreen. Fortunately, there is a faster way to do this: <kbd>F11</kbd> is bound to the "toggle fullscreen" function. If you're using a laptop then <kbd>F11</kbd> probably defaults to adjusting your volume or similar, and you'll need to use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> instead. The <kbd>fn</kbd> key is usually located in the bottom-left, under <kbd>shift</kbd>.

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch! A very simple shortcut indeed.

Comment: This doesn't work in minecraft version 1.9.4 and OSX version 10.11.4

Comment: Works in Minecraft 1.12.2 on High Sierra.