# Can Minecraft not open in fullscreen and cover my entire desktop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open up Minecraft, it automatically goes 'full screen' and covers my entire desktop. It can be played as usual, but I prefer having it split screen with YouTube while I am playing, and since Minecraft is fullscreen, I can't do that. I tried to perform the three finger swipe gesture, but Minecraft simply minimizes itself.

Is there a way for me to make Minecraft not fullscreen? I have a MacBook Air 13".

Comment: So are you asking for a borderless window?

Comment: The shortcut for toggling fullscreen mode is F11. Try it out and see, whether it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I alt-tab out of fullscreen Minecraft with the game still running (Mac)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132725/how-do-i-alt-tab-out-of-fullscreen-minecraft-with-the-game-still-running-mac)

Comment: How is this question unclear? The original poster is 
just asking how to play Minecraft windowed.

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting F11 or go into settings to go out of full-screen

Answer (score 1):

You should find the full screen toggle in the settings. Then, you can adjust the window's resolution in the Launcher.